# Concat in MySQL with condition

Tags: mysql

I have three columns in my table - `company_name, first_name, last_name`. In the result of a `SELECT`, I'd like to have only one column: `name`, which should contain content of `company_name` if it's not `NULL` or concatenation of `first_name +' '+  last_name`, if the `company_name` is not set.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT IFNULL(company_name,CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name)) as NAME
```